# How to create custom module for Microsoft Navision

Tags: .net, erp, navision

I'm a .Net developer and I'm trying to figure out how is it possible to build custom module for Microsoft Navision. The Navision community seems to be be a small and close one. I didn't find a lot of informations except from the mibuso.com website.

- Do you know other good source of informations ?

After some search it appears that there is two possible way to create custom module on an existing Navision installation:

- Create dll that will be integrated in a way into Navision ? Any documentation ?
- Create external web applications that will access Navision data through WebServices ?

Did someone have informations about that kind of development ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that open information on Nav development is rather scarce, and mibuso.com is probably the most active community you can find on the Internet. Development documentation is distributed mostly through [the partnersource](https://mbs.microsoft.com/partnersource/) , but it requires a partner's account to access.
Now a lot of documentation is published on msdn, so you could look there. It is not as rich as .NET library, still quite useful.

1. [Extending Nav functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169423(v=nav.71).aspx). Some how-to topics on extending functionality via COM, .NET Interop and custom controls.
2. [Creating and publishing Web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355036(v=nav.71).aspx). Overview and several walk-throughs on web services in Nav.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alexander. I'll have a look on these sources.
Do you know what is the most common and easy way to build custom module ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: You're welcome! I see, you accepted the answer, so I presume you did find what you were looking for? As for the most common and easy way of building extensions, I would say that this is .NET interoperability - you develop a .NET assembly in a usual way, then just declare a variable of 'DotNet' type in C/AL with a reference to your assembly. But that's all described in the msdn article above.